# Java robots.txt parser with wildcard support

Tags: java, web-applications, wildcard, robots.txt

I'm looking for a robots.txt parser in Java, which supports the same [pattern matching rules](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40367) as the Googlebot.

I've found some librairies to parse robots.txt files, but none of them supports Googlebot-style pattern matching :

- Heritrix (there is an [open issue](https://webarchive.jira.com/browse/HER-1621) on this subject)
- Crawler4j (looks like the same implementation as Heritrix)
- jrobotx

Does anyone know of a java library that can do this ?

Comment: I believe ex-crawler will work. http://sourceforge.net/projects/ex-crawler/

Answer (score 1):

Nutch seems to be using a combination of [crawler-commons](http://code.google.com/p/crawler-commons/) with [some custom code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/nutch/trunk/src/plugin/lib-http/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/http/api/RobotRulesParser.java) (see RobotsRulesParser.java). I'm not sure of the current state of afairs, though.

In particular, the issue [NUTCH-1455](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1455) looks to be quite related to your needs:

> If the user-agent name(s) configured in http.robots.agents contains spaces it is not matched even if is exactly contained in the robots.txt
>   http.robots.agents = "Download Ninja,*"

Perhaps its worth it to try/patch/submit the fix :)